# What are the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax values for Australia?

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to crop the bioclimatic data from WorldClim.org to get environmental features only for the Australian habitat using the `extent()` method. Finally, I plan to combine the bioclimatic data with the occurrence data to perform species distribution modelling.

However, I cannot understand how the **xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax** spatial coordinate values are provided to the `biocli<-stack(crop(bioclimatic,(extent(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))))` method.

Comment: You can use st_bbox function to get desired values. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/1.0-8/topics/st_bbox

Comment: Based on the NE countries dataset, your workflow might encompass sth like `sf::read_sf("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp") |> dplyr::filter(ADMIN == "Australia") |> sf::st_bbox()` resulting in `c(xmin = 112.919444207, ymin = -54.7504208309999, xmax = 159.106455925, ymax = -9.24016692499993)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extent can be extracted from another object. So if you have, e.g. SpatialPolygons for Australia, `aus` you can do

```
librayr(raster)
aus <- raster::getData("GADM", country="Australia", level=1)
e <- extent(aus)
e
#class      : Extent 
#xmin       : 112.9211 
#xmax       : 159.1092 
#ymin       : -55.11694 
#ymax       : -9.142176
```

You can also [look at a map](https://www.worldatlas.com/maps/australia) and do something like

```
 e <- extent(100, 160, -10, -50)
```

And you can refine that with trial and error.

Moreover, you can do

```
 plot(bioclimatic, 1)
 e <- drawExtent() # now click twice on the map, to create an extent
```

With "terra" (the replacement of "raster"), replace `extent` with `ext` and `drawExtent` with `draw`.

Comment: Thank you very much!